# How to append empty line in text files using java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem, I wrote this method to append records in a text file using java but the problem is when I append new record, it appends in the same line of the last record and not in a new line.

How can I append each record in a separate line??

Here is my code:

```
public void addProduct(int id, String name, String type, String brand, int quantity, int day1, int month1, int year1, int day2, int month2, int year2, String company, String name2, String address, int phone_no)

{
Formatter x = null;
try{
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt", true);
x = new Formatter(f);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//System.out.println("NO Database");
}
x.format("%d %s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s %d\n\n\n",id,name,type,brand,quantity,day1,month1,year1,day2,month2,year2,company,name2,address,phone_no);
x.close();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `%n` format to append a newline within your format.

This may work better than the only `\n` character, which may not appear as a new line in some systems.

See the **Conversions** section of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> 'n'   line separator  The result is the platform-specific line separator

Answer (score 2):

Mena descripes a pretty good solution for you.
For the completness. In case you are using `Java < 1.5` you 
can also use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to get the `linebreak` of the operating system.

`%n` is available in `Java > 1.5`